# How to get the pymongo collections based on updatedtimestamp in unix format

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection which is having updatedtimestamp column. I am passing from and to date using an external yaml file. But updated timestamp column is in the UNIX timestamp.

Any suggestions on this? Or anyway to bring the latest records based on updatedtimestamp which is captured in unixtimestamp?

**data format**

```
id:1223344444444
createTimestamp:1640845784796
updateTimestamp:1640845784796
deleteTimestamp:null
uuid:"abcdefgh"
```

**YAML file**

```
collection_name: 
incremental: true
date_field: updateTimestamp
start_date: 2022-01-01
end_date: 2022-01-02
hours_interval: 24
```

**Incremental query**

```
# Build interval dates
            initial_dt_t = datetime.combine(day, datetime.min.time()) + timedelta(
                minutes=lower_limit
            )
            final_dt_t = datetime.combine(day, datetime.min.time()) + timedelta(
                minutes=upper_limit
            )

            initial_dt = mktime(initial_dt_t.timetuple())
            final_dt = mktime(final_dt_t.timetuple())

            print("initial-dt")
            print(initial_dt_t)
            print(final_dt_t)

            print("unix")
            print(initial_dt)
            print(final_dt)

            # Connect to MongoDB
            mongo_client = MongoClient(MONGODB_URI)
            mongo_db = mongo_client[MONGODB_NAME]
            collection = mongo_db[COLLECTION_NAME]

            # Build aggregation pipeline for MongoDB
            or_list = []
            print("coming to query")

            # Check if there is a single field
            if "date_field" in config.keys():
                or_list.append(
                    {
                        config["date_field"]: {
                            "$gte": initial_dt,
                            "$lt": final_dt,
                        }
                    }
                )

            # Check if there are multiple date fields
            if "date_fields" in config.keys():
                for date_field in config["date_fields"]:
                    or_list.append(
                        {
                            config["date_field"]: {
                                "$gte": initial_dt,
                                "$lt": final_dt,
                            }
                        }
                    )

            # Get data from MongoDB
            query = {"$or": or_list}

            # Keep track of batch number
            batch_number = 0
            print("chunk")
            data = pd.DataFrame(list(collection.find(query)))
            print("dataframe")
            print(data)
```

Comment: In your `for` loop, you repeatedly add the same `initial_dt` and `final_dt`.  I doubt that is intended.  It's not clear what you want to do here ... or even what the problem is.

Comment: Sure Rick. I have to pass mongodb query based on date range. But I have only updated time stamp column which is in unix time stamp basis. Is there a way to filter the date range in unix timestamp ?

Comment: I'm guessing that `updateTimestamp`, etc., in the collection documents are in integer milliseconds since the epoch.  You can convert your `start_date`, etc., to milliseconds since the epoch with `int(datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(start_date).timestamp())*1000`.