# Have to write a query converting Epoch column to timestamp in Mongodb

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo-3.x

I have a collection that is having updated timestamps in epoch milliseconds. I have a python config that gets start date and end date parameters.

I have to form a query to filter this data

```
_id:61cd51d8e788b021539c1a6e
id:null
createTimestamp:1640845784796
updateTimestamp:1640845784796
deleteTimestamp:null
```

python.yaml
start date - 16-Feb-2022 (something like this)

```
{createTimestamp: {
        $gte: ISODate("2022-02-16T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2022-02-17T00:00:00.000Z")
    }
}
```

is there a way to convert the start date to epoch and pass that to Mongoquery?

something in python

```
startdate = int(datetime.fromisoformat("2022-01-01").timestamp())*1000 
enddate = int(datetime.fromisoformat("2022-02-16").timestamp())*1000                                                                                                       
query =  {"updateTimestamp":{"$gte":startdate,"$lt":enddate}}
# myresult = collection.find().limit(5)     
myresult = collection.find(query)
```

still, listing whole data? any issue here?

Comment: Is [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) what you are looking for?

Comment: Is this the same question you ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71094238/how-to-get-the-pymongo-collections-based-on-updatedtimestamp-in-unix-format "Link to your other question-->").  You didn't respond to all the questions there.